# How to read shutter count on Canon EOS 6D Mark II?

Tags: canon-6d, shutter-actuations, windows-10

How can I read the shutter count on Canon EOS 6D Mark II on Windows with a preferrably free tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.eosmsg.com/ works on Windows PC but costs about $5.00 USD. It is a Chinese website so the language and translations are a little "clunky",  but it does work.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Was it free? Or did you have to pay? And if so, how much was it?

Comment: I had to pay, USD 5.18. I guess that's less than spending hours trying different tools